# How can I use Python to get the selected property in the curve editor in MotionBuilder?

Tags: python, motionbuilder

I can only obtain the TRS level at the moment, and cannot obtain parameters such as tx/ty:

```
obj.PropertyList.Find('Lcl Translation').IsFocus
```

But property not get children.

Comment: property doesn't have children, the children are on animation node level, for example prop.GetAnimationNode().Nodes[1]. Anyway, I don't think that base FBComponent Selected flag anyhow connected to the actual mobu selection

Comment: I've also with this, I'm not sure it's something accessible to the python API. A potential alternative is to use the properties from the selected keys.